# Mean, Var, and Std

Tags: python, arrays, std, mean, var

**The Task is**
You are given a 2-D array of size X.
Your task is to find:

1. The mean along axis
2. The var along axis
3. The std along axis

**Input Format**
The first line contains the space separated values of  and .
The next  lines contains  space separated integers.

**Output Format**
First, print the mean.
Second, print the var.
Third, print the std.

**Sample Input**

```
2 2
1 2
3 4
```

**Sample Output**

```
[ 1.5  3.5]
[ 1.  1.]
1.11803398875
```

***My Code:***

```
import numpy
N,M = map(int, input().split(" "))
A = numpy.array([input().split() for _ in range(N)],int)
print(numpy.mean(A, axis = 1))
print(numpy.var(A, axis = 0))
print(round(numpy.std(A, axis = None),11))
```

**The output:**
[image]

*I seem to have some indentation issue or my printed result than the expected, there is a space in front of the first vertical elements of the array.
Am I doing anything wrong?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere between importing numpy and printing numpy data. It tells the numpy print formatter to use the default settings from numpy version 1.13 instead of numpy version 1.14 (which is the current version). The problem-set results are canned, and were apparently done with the old numpy, so if you don't do this you get various format mismatches which causes failures in the tests even when you got the actual answers correct.

So use `np.set_printoptions(legacy='1.13')`

```
import numpy as np 

n,m = map(int, input().split())
b = []
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    b.append(a)

b = np.array(b)

np.set_printoptions(legacy='1.13')
print(np.mean(b, axis = 1))
print(np.var(b, axis = 0))
print(np.std(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

For python3, I have used the following code:

```
import numpy
N, M = map(int, input().split())
A = numpy.array([list(map(int, input().split())) for n in range(N)])
print(numpy.mean(A, axis = 1))
print(numpy.var(A, axis = 0))
print(numpy.round(numpy.std(A), 11))
```